# Typescript interface generics are type checked but not inferred

Tags: typescript

In the sample code below, when implementing `MyInterface`...

- If I do not specify an input type, it is inferred to be `any`
- If I specify an incorrect input type, it warns me that this is incorrect

If it can detect an incorrect type, why can it not infer the correct type?

```
interface MyInterface<T = any> {
    myFunction(input: T): void;
}

class MyClass implements MyInterface<number> {
    // input inferred as 'any'
    myFunction(input) {}
}

class MyClass2 implements MyInterface<number> {
    // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'
    myFunction(input: string) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little more complicated than it looks in general.  There is an [open suggestion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23911).